# Get latest previous year if possible

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to use Linq to get the latest previous year, if not possible then the earliest year to the current year (including current year).

So if Date.Now.Year = 2017 and there was

Ex: Given 2011, 2013, 2018 - Then it would return 2013.

Ex: Given 2017, 2018 - Then it would return 2017.

Ex: Given 2019, 2025 - Then it would return 2019.

My attempt only for the previous year

```
    Dim selectedYear = (
                                From year In years
                                Where year < Date.Now.Year
                                Order By year descending
                                select year
                            ).First
```

This fails if there are no years earlier than the current year. If this is too complex for linq then I am open to other ideas to do it succinctly

Comment: I'm not certain, but what about `Where year <= Date.Now.Year`?

Comment: Or even `).FirstOrDefault(Date.Now.Year)`

Comment: "Ex: Given 2019, 2025 - Then it would return 2019." this makes no seance if  `Date.Now.Year = 2017`  since "...I am trying to use Linq to get the latest previous year..."

Comment: @shadow: He did explain it though. He wants the max year prior to the current year, if one exists. If such a year doesn't exist, then he settles for the closest year to the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim selectedYear = (
                     From year In years
                     Where year < Date.Now.Year
                     Order By year Descending
                     Select year
                  ).FirstOrDefault() Or years.Min
```

Comment: For future googlers, here is what I used to test : https://dotnetfiddle.net/buRjks

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions Team's "Interactive Extensions" (NuGet "Ix-Main"). This library gives you a bunch of handy extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`. You could end up doing this:

```
var years = new [] { 2019, 2025 };

var secondLast = years.SkipLast(1).Last();
```

That returns `2019`.

Obviously order it first if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the `Order By` clause should be enough to get the expected results:

```
Dim selectedYear = (
    From year In years
    Order By If(year < Date.Now.Year, 0, 1),
        Math.Abs(Date.Now.Year - year)).First
```

In short, the first part of the `Order By` clause sorts all years prior to the current year ahead of other years. The 2nd part sorts by how close the year is to the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var today = new DateTime(2017,12,12);
var years = new [] { 2011, 2013, 2018 };

var penultimate = years.Where(y=> y <= today.Year).OrderByDescending(y => y).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

penultimate = penultimate == 0 ? years.OrderBy(y => y).Take(1).First() : penultimate;
```